# parse Dutch NDW xml

Tags: python, performance, xml-parsing, traffic

I am trying to parse the XML file from the Dutch NDW which contains every minute the trafficspeed on many Dutch motorways. I use this example file: http://www.ndw.nu/downloaddocument/e838c62446e862f5b6230be485291685/Reistijden.zip

I am trying to parse the traveltime data in variables with Python but i am struggling.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import urllib2
url = "http://weburloffile.nl/ndw/Reistijden.xml"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
namespaces = {
    'soap': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
    'a': 'http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0'
     }
dom = ElementTree.fromstring(response.read)
names = dom.findall(
        'soap:Envelope'
        '/a:duration',
        namespaces,
)
#print names
for duration in names:
    print(duration.text)
```

I get this new error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    dom = ElementTree.fromstring(response.read)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1311, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1651, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, 0)
TypeError: Parse() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not instancemethod
```

How to parse this (complex) xml correctly?

-- changed it into read as suggested by comment

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the XML parsing; it's that you are using the `response` object incorrectly. [`urllib2.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) returns a file-like object that does not have a `content` attribute. Instead, you should be calling `read` on it:

```
dom = ElementTree.fromstring(response.read())
```